# 2-Way SSL using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, ssl, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to PhoneGap and I have this question.
I have a REST API deployed on Weblogic Server, the API requires that the client who consumes it needs to do it under 2-Way SSL Policy due to internal security standards in my company.

Does PhoneGap admits 2-Way SSL Communication? (The platforms are Android and iPhone)

Comment: what do you mean, 2-way ssl? ssl is a bi-directional protocol already. do you mean requiring clients to have certificates to authenticate themselves to the server, v.s. the usual server-has-cert-so-client-can-trust-server?

Comment: Hi @MarcB. By definition, there are 2 types of SSL, 1-way SSL and 2-way SSL. In 2-way SSL yo require exactly the statement that you mentioned "requiring clients to have certificates to authenticate themselves to the server". Does PhoneGap supports this?